# Multiple database support using hibernate

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, postgresql

I am working on an application that currently supports MSSQL and MYSQL and now we need to make it compatible with Oracle and Postgresql too. We have a  strong dependency on the Id generated for the records as we use the same Id to generate some logical identifiers for the records.Therefore we want each of the tables to have it's own sequence such that each new record has a new logical identifier which is in the sequence n,n+1,n+2 and the logical identifiers will therefore be XYn,XY(n+1),XY(n+2).

Using the generation strategy AUTO for the Id worked with both MSSQL and MYSQL but doesn't work with Oracle or Postgresql as the generation strategy AUTO ultimately maps to SEQUENCE for these databases. I need to maintain a common code for all these databases and cannot afford to make any database changes.
Please suggest some ways to get this done.

Comment: As I recall it is possible to create sequences in POSTGRE and use it for ID generation in a way suits you. Did you check documentation for @Generated ??

Comment: What's wrong with SEQUENCES?

Comment: A sequence, from what i know is shared  by  all the tables in the database.   The logical identifiers i am talking about have to maintained for multiple tables, therefore each table needs a sequence of it's own.

Comment: sequence is independent "object" in Oracle. You can use one SEQUENCE for all tables a or you can create  one SEQUENCE for each table. Also each sequence can have different initial value a also different next/step value. You can also use for example only one SEQUENCE for all tables having next = 100 and then simply add entity id to the last two digits of the generated id.

Comment: Thanx for the Information! It was helpful. But i wonder if using a Generation strategy AUTO with the annotation @SequenceGenerator will work with MYSQL and MSSQL. If it does....problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be portable across every RDBMS, `GenerationStrategy=TABLE` is a solution. Check for some information in [this article](http://www.developerscrappad.com/408/java/java-ee/ejb3-jpa-3-ways-of-generating-primary-key-through-generatedvalue/)

Comment: Upvote because there is no mention of performance limitations and this basically is the only way to make hibernate do all the work for you.

Comment: Exactly what i am worried about, keeping a common code is the requirement but the performance is even more important. The performance is the USP of the application, i cannot let the performance suffer just to accommodate another database

Comment: Unless you will develop own solution as part of JPA, you will have to deploy appliaction version for each RDBMS, or at least dedicated DAO module that suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use UUID instead of sequence numbers? That is more portable.

In Java there is already an implementation of UUID.

As far as I remember there is no built-in sequence mechanism in Oracle, so you can't use the ID generator from Hibernate.

Comment: The reason we cannot use a UUID for IDs is the dependency that i have mentioned in my question itself. The logical identifiers that are used for each record are generated using the ID's and UUID does not provide an ID that a user can relate to i.e. the ids generated are random.